# Empty lines removed and added according to GIT

Tags: git, line-endings

This started happening without any clear reason:

[image]

Pic is from Source Tree GUI, but the same issue can be seen in the terminal view.

My intuition is that it has something to do with line endings, but I don't know how to confirm it.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're using an editor that automatically removes trailing whitespace. When you've edited the file earlier with an editor that keeps trailing whitespace on newlines (to keep indentation) this behavior may occur.

EDIT: You may also be able to ignore whitespace changes in github by appending ?w=1  to the url (https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets)

Comment: You're right, my text editor is configured to remove trailing spaces and IDE is configured to add it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a line endings thing. Open both versions in an editor that is able to display white-space characters (e.g. Atom), then you'll see.

Or if you happen to have Beyond Compare around, just use that to diff the files. Beyond Compare displays white-space differences.